# how to highlight README.md File using Codemirror

Tags: javascript, markdown, editor, codemirror

Now I am making an Editor using showdown.js with codemirror

> I want to highlight the showdown library syntax (like #Heading, **Bold**, ``` Code ```)

There is my Code

```js
  let codemirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(
    document.getElementById("book-content"),
    {
      lineNumbers: true,
      lineWrapping: true,
      mode: "mustache",
      htmlMode: true,
      styleActiveLine: true,
      autoCloseTags: true,
      theme: "monokai",
      keyMap: "sublime",
      showCursorWhenSelecting: true,
    }
  );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codemirror.net/theme/monokai.css" />

<textarea rows="15" id="book-content" placeholder="Enter Your README.md ...">
#Heading 1
##Heading 2

    <h1>Code Here</h1>

[Hyper Link](http://google.com/)

*Italic*

**Bold**
- foo1
    - bar
    - baz
- foo2
</textarea>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/keymap/sublime.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/addon/selection/active-line.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/addon/display/placeholder.js"></script>
```

I try this with the following code

```
<style>
.highlightred {
  color: var(--red);
}
.highlightorange {
  color: var(--orange);
}
.highlightgreen {
  color: var(--green);
}
.highlightblue {
  color: var(--blue);
}
</style>
```

```
<script>
const hightlightArray = [
  ["#", "highlightgreen"],
  ["+", "highlightorange"],
  ["-", "highlightorange"],
  ["*", "highlightorange"],
  [")", "highlightblue"],
  ["(", "highlightblue"],
  ["[", "highlightblue"],
  ["]", "highlightblue"],
  ["{", "highlightblue"],
  ["}", "highlightblue"],
  ["`", "highlightred"],
];

function highlightCodeMirror() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".CodeMirror-line span").forEach((element) => {
    let Value = element.textContent;
    HightLighted = Value;
    for (let i = 0; i < htmlEntities.length; i++) {
      const ThisElement1 = htmlEntities[i];
      HightLighted = HightLighted.replaceAll(
        ThisElement1[0],
        ThisElement1[1]
      );
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < hightlightArray.length; i++) {
      const ThisElement2 = hightlightArray[i];
      HightLighted = HightLighted.replaceAll(
        ThisElement2[0],
        `<span class='${ThisElement2[1]}'>${ThisElement2[0]}</span>`
      );
    }
    element.innerHTML = HightLighted;
  });
}
  setInterval(() => {
    highlightCodeMirror();
  }, 500);
</script>
```

This Code is working. But The codemirror behavior becomes bad. The active-line.js not works and the blinking cursor not shown in textarea.

Please Anyone helps me to solve this issue

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeMirror already has many processes to reflow DOM. Adding more, especially `innerHTML` on a timer, can conflict with CodeMirror and affect performance.

The best option is to use CodeMirror processes that are already available and write a  wrapper function.

There is a **markdown** `mode` that may suit your example. Here is the CodeMirror [demo](https://codemirror.net/demo/folding.html) with a markdown section.

You can also check [CodeMirror: Overlay Parser Demo](https://codemirror.net/demo/mustache.html) for an example using `overlay`.

```js
CodeMirror.defineMode("mustache", function(config, parserConfig) {
  var mustacheOverlay = {
    token: function(stream, state) {
      var ch;
      if (stream.match("{{")) {
        while ((ch = stream.next()) != null)
          if (ch == "}" && stream.next() == "}") {
            stream.eat("}");
            return "mustache";
          }
      }
      while (stream.next() != null && !stream.match("{{", false)) {}
      return null;
    }
  };
  return CodeMirror.overlayMode(CodeMirror.getMode(config, parserConfig.backdrop || "text/html"), mustacheOverlay);
});
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {mode: "mustache"});
```

There is also [keyword](https://github.com/erosman/CodeMirror-plus/tree/main/addon/mode) CodeMirror addon that allows you to highlight keywords.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I use [gfm.js](https://codemirror.net/mode/gfm/) to highlight the README.md file